# To find a specfic equation $z-\frac{1}{s\ln(s)}-n\ln(s)==0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here I want to find the solution to the following equation
$$z-\frac{1}{s\ln(s)}-n\ln(s)=0,$$
where $z$ and $n$ are constants.
Here the aim is to find the solution $s=?$.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What about $(z,s)$ ? Real, positive ... Can you give details ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  $z$ is real and $s$ is the Laplace pair of time $t$.

Comment: Can you please explain, in which range you are searching for solutions (e.g. $s<<1$ or $s>>1$) and what the ranges for $z$ and $n$ are?

Comment: @cdalitz   I am interested in long time behavior, i.e., $s\to 0$.

Comment: Are you sure that there are solutions for $s\to 0$ at all? With th substitution $s=e^{-x}$ this is equivalent to the solution of $zx+e^x +nx=0$ for $x\to\infty$, and $e^x$ will always run away.

Comment: @cdalitz  what you said above makes sense. Here if just take $s\to 0$, the term $1/s/\ln(s)$ is the leading term.  Note that here $n$ is the number of renewals in the renewal process, i.e., $n$ will increase with the increase of $t$ (decrease of $s$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(s)=z-\frac{1}{s\log(s)}-n\log(s)$$
Let $s=e^x$ and consider the function
$$g(x)=n x^2- zx+e^{-x}$$ Its first derivative
$$g'(x)=2 n x-e^{-x}-z$$
cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{z}{2 n}+W\left(\frac{1}{2 n}e^{-\frac{z}{2 n}}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.
We also have
$$g''(x)=e^{-x}+2n$$ which is always positive if $n \geq 0$.

If $g(x_*)<0$, make a series expansion of $g(x)$ around $x_*$
$$g(x)=g(x_*)+\frac{1}{2} (x-x_*)^2 g''(x_*)+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ and solve it to get, as an *approximation*,
$$x_\pm=x_*\pm \sqrt{-2 \frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

Trying for $n=3$ and $z=7$ this gives
$$x_*=\frac{7}{6}
+W\left(\frac{1}{6 e^{7/6}}\right)\approx 1.21607 \implies g(x_*) \approx-3.77962$$ This gives
$$x_-\approx 0.120362 \qquad \text{and}\qquad x_+\approx 2.31177$$ while the "exact" solutions, obtained by Newton method, are

$$x_-\approx 0.132651 \qquad \text{and}\qquad x_+\approx 2.31920$$

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the equation after ``and solve it to get, as an approximation''?

Comment: Do you solve the equation $g(x)=g(x_*)+1/2(x-x_*)^2 g^{''}(x_*)$ with $g(x)=-xf(x)$? Then you get $x_{\pm}=x_{*}\pm\sqrt{...}$.

Comment: Thanks, now I more or less understand your methods.

Answer (score 2):

Does it help to substitute $x=\ln s$? Then the equation becomes
$$zx - e^{-x} -nx^2=0$$
which can be solved approximately in the limits of large $x$ (then $e^{-x}\approx 0$ and small $x$ (then $e^{-x}\approx 1-x$).

Comment: Here the log function decays very slowly. For example$s=10^{-7}$, then $ ln(s)=-7=x$.  It can be seen that $x$ is not very large.

Comment: Obviously this depends on the values for z and n. Do you know anything about them? Moreover, you can readily find a numeric solution with your favorite software package (e.g. *uniroot* in R) for moderate values. My suggestions can be used to obtain asymptotic approximations.

Comment: You are right. I can get your points.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts that may help.

Similar equations can often be solved, at least numerically, in 'general' by the application of a numerical method as have been developed in the field of Numerical Analysis.

See, for example, this [Wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on Newton's method, also known as the Newton–Raphson method.

This may not be the direct algebraic solution that you are seeking, however, plotting the solution as a function of the underlying parameter values, does, at least, present a graphical-based general solution.

While not likely, you may be able to also identify the underlying functional forms composing the solution. In this regard, try, for example, examing plots where one of the parameters is set at a constant value.

Relatedly, take the derivative of the target equation and work with that (where the solution then becomes a differential equation exercise), or try applying some variable transformations. In this case, I would use y = Exp (s), and then relook at the equation and perhaps employing series expansions.

Can proceed again to examine a graphical solution for aid.